# Term reference field won't display

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to add tags to my blog posts on my Drupal 7 site. I've added the `Term Reference` field to the content type and when I add a blog post it is letting me add tags without a problem, however despite the field being visible in the 'Manage Display' tab I can't get them to show up when viewing the blog entry.

I know that the field is working because I have the `Metatag` module installed and that's producing metatags from the field token. I've checked the page source though and the field isn't even there but hidden because of CSS.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Does it be removed in template.php or *.tpl.php?

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: Maybe you're using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) or a template file for your node. If you switch to the drupal default theme (bartik) does the field show up?

Comment: @CodeNext I'm using a theme generated by Artisteer but I've modified it heavily. I haven't seen anything that could remove the field, but I have just switched to `batik` and the field does appear?

Comment: Can you check, Setting of your  theme under Appearence. And can you find whether your theme provides the option of enabling/disabling Taxonomy display. I read in one of the issue, where the theme itself was providing this feature and it was disabled and that person, did solve by this way. Might work.

Comment: @CodeNext Thanks for your help. Please see the answer I just added.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my theme was hiding any term reference fields by default, which I discovered after switching back to the default theme (thank you too @NoSssweat for suggesting I do this).

I created the theme using Artisteer (please keep comments about my decision to do so to a minimum - I only use it as a starting point) and following @JimmyKo's comment I found the following lines in the `node.tpl.php` file:

```php
$terms = themename_art_terms_D7($content);
hide($content[$terms['#field_name']]);
```

After I commented these out the term reference field started appearing. Thinking back, I may have ticked an option in Artisteer to say that I didn't want tags to appear so I can't definitely lay the blame on the software!